# Haskell Win32 issue: Application does not exit despite program sending WM_QUIT message

Tags: haskell, winapi

I am compiling with GHC 8.0 on Windows 8. I have written a simple Win32 program to display a window, but when I close the window, the program does not exit. The code is below. Can anyone help?

```
module Main where

import System.Win32.DLL
import Graphics.Win32
import Data.Bits  
import Control.Monad
import Control.Exception
import System.Exit
import Graphics.Win32.Window.PostMessage

main = do 
  hInstance <- getModuleHandle Nothing
  let classname = mkClassName "H3WindowClass"
  let
    wndclass = (
      cS_OWNDC .|. cS_HREDRAW .|. cS_VREDRAW,
      hInstance,
      Nothing,
      Nothing,
      Nothing,
      Nothing,
      classname)
  registerClass wndclass



  let opts = wS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW .|. wS_VISIBLE
  hwnd <- createWindowEx 0 classname "H3" opts Nothing Nothing Nothing Nothing Nothing Nothing hInstance window   

  allocaMessage $ \msg -> mwhilst (getMessage msg (Just hwnd)) $ do
    translateMessage msg
    dispatchMessage msg


mwhilst :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m ()
mwhilst mb act = do
  b <- mb
  if b then act >> mwhilst mb act else return ()


window :: WindowClosure
window hwnd msg wparam lparam
  | msg == wM_CLOSE = do
      postQuitMessage 0
      return 0
  | otherwise = defWindowProc (Just hwnd) msg wparam lparam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handler to `WM_CLOSE` you should call `DestroyWindow` to destroy the window. You also need to handle the ensuing `WM_DESTROY` message by calling `PostQuitMessage`.

```
window :: WindowClosure
window hwnd msg wparam lparam
  | msg == wM_CLOSE = do
      destroyWindow hwnd 
      return 0
  | msg == wM_DESTROY = do
      postQuitMessage 0
      return 0
  | otherwise = defWindowProc (Just hwnd) msg wparam lparam
```

MSDN covers this pattern, for instance, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff381396.aspx